comma in a Kernel equation
I have difficulties understanding the part h,1 in the definition below. What is this ,1 following the h? The code is C++.
double Temp = Kernel((X(n) - X(m)) / h,1) / h;

The mathematical form of the equation is:
1/nh * Kernel((X(n) - X(m))/h)

Could it be a mistake?

Comma operator, is this you?

1 is the second argument to Kernel; the first is (X(n) - X(m)) / h. You need to check the documentation or code and see what Kernel is supposed to do.

There is no obvious relationship between the function or class Kernel, and Kernel in your formula (it's not an equation; an equation specifies an equality between two things, such as y = x + 1).
